# How to pass a parameter from a thread to a function in c

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I would like to pass a parameter from my main() into my function. Please let me know how should I do that. I  saw some methods in Internet but they didn't work. 
Here is the code:

```
void *deliver(int *i)
{
    int *ThreadID=(int *)tid;

    //Here I would like to do some comparing on arrays using i parameter
    //a[i]>b[i] As an example

}

void main ()
{

    pthread_t t2_deliver[100];

    //input var
    printf("By using this code you can apply T threads on ordering list ;) \n");
    printf("->*******************************************************************************<-\n");
    printf("Please enter the number of threads(T):\n");
    scanf("%d",&threadnum);
    for (i=0; i<threadnum; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&t2_deliver[i],NULL,deliver,&i);
    }
```

Comment: `struct`s are often used to group data together... So perhaps defining a custom piece of data and passing a pointer to that, instead of *just* a plain integer pointer, will do the trick...

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements and the end of the `main()` function.

Comment: when calling system functions (scanf, pghread)create()), always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code declares an array of 100 'pthread_t` elements. (I.E. max 100 threads,  but the interaction with the user neither mentions this limit nor checks the value the user entered to assure it is in the range 1...100

Comment: the signature for a 'pthread' function is `void * threadName( void * arg )`  not `void * threadName( int * arg )`.   Strongly suggest reading/understnding the man pages for those functions that you are using

Comment: the variable `tid` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error that I see is you try to cast not what is in i (argument of function) but in some variable tid.

In principle thread function (in your case deliver) accepts as an argument void pointer, which later can be casted to what you sent, so just to play by the rules I would recommend you that you change function definition so it accepts void pointer as argument, not int pointer. It should not make any difference but is more correct. Why is this better: void pointer is a pointer to some data we don't know yet what it is so we need to cast it in function, this gives us the freedom that we could pass to function whatever we want from simple integers to complex structures. If you then want to get the value that is stored on location passed as function argument you dereference it with * operator. So I'm suggesting you make this modifications, thread function should look something like this:

```
void *deliver(void *i){
    // in p there is integer pointer to argument i
    int *p = (int *)i;
    // now in ThreadID we have value of argument we passed to function in main (value at address i)
    int ThreadID = *p;

    //Here I would like to do some comparing on arrays using i parameter
    //a[i]>b[i] As an example
}
```

and when creating threads just to do it right I would do this:

```
pthread_create(&t2_deliver[i],NULL,deliver,(void *)&i);
```

Maybe some of the things like type of pointer are not necessary but I think it is more correct and by my experience this works fine and you get the freedom to pass to function everything you want if you then cast it and dereference it correctly. Hope this helps.

**Update and fix:**

As mentioned in a comment below by Jonathan Leffler passing address of i in for loop (main function) is wrong, because then all threads point with their arguments to the same integer i in memory and effectively to the same value. There are plenty of workarounds, two are mentioned below by Jonathan Leffler, my favourite is constructing array of ids and then assagning and sending each id in array to each of threads:

```
ind tid[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    tid[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&t2_deliver[i],NULL,deliver,(void *)&tid[i]);
}
```

Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: There's a lot of good material here, but passing `(void *)&i` to the thread undoes it all.  By the time the thread gets going, the value of `i` may have changed because the `main()` code has iterated.  You must make sure that what's passed to the thread doesn't change because `main()` or another thread is using it.  There are a couple of ways around it.  One is an array of thread ID values: `int tid[100]; … for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { arr[i] = i; pthread_create(…, &arr[i]); }`.  Another is to pass the integer by value: `pthread_create(…, (void *)(uintptr_t)i);`.

Comment: @tadejm_95: Thanks for your answer however I got the following error:
usr/include/pthread.h:312:5: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(int *)’
 int pthread_create(pthread_t * __restrict, const pthread_attr_t * __restrict,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @tadejm_95 Could you help me that why this occurs. Thanks

Comment: @tadejm_95: I also have this warning:  warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         pthread_create(&t2_deliver[i],NULL,deliver,(void *)&i);
                                            ^~~~~~~

Comment: did you change the argument in deliver function declaration from int * to void * as i wrote above? And check if the call in for loop is as I wrote above. Check also update and fix in my answer, because I see you still pass a pointer to i in pthread_create function

Comment: @tadejm_95: No I forgot that, thanks a lot, It works now!

Answer (score 3):

You have a logical error in your code. All threads you create will have a pointer to the *same* `i`, meaning it will have the same value in all threads, and will most likely be out of bounds as the threads will run *after* the loop creating the threads.

One possible solution is to use casting and the standard `intptr_t` to pass the *value* to the thread functions:

```
pthread_create(..., (void*) (intptr_t) i);
```

And in the thread:

```
void *deliver(int *p)
{
    int i = (int) (intptr_t) p;
    ...
}
```